# Rails - Heroku - Push notifications work via Postman but not via my Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, expo, scheduler

I want to send push notifications to devices using expo.
I am successfully getting expo_push_token for each device that has enabled access and I am also successfully able to make the request using Postman.
Here is my Postman request:
POST request to: https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send

```
{
 "to": "ExponentPushToken[xxx]",
 "title": "yesahhhh",
 "body": "lkajdsljaslda"
}
```

Headers include:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-type: application/json
Accept encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: exp.host
```

So, the above work as it should via postman.

However, I cannot get it to work when I run the Heroku command:
`heroku run rake run_job`

The run_job method is referenced in my rails app in 2 places:

`lib/task/scheduler.rake`:

```
task :run_job => :environment do
    puts "Running Job..."
    User.run_job
    puts "done!" 
end
```

`user.rb`:

```
  def self.run_job
    User.all.each do |u|
      if u.expo_push_token.present?
        require 'net/http'
        require 'json'
        begin
          uri = URI('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send')
          http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
          http.use_ssl = true

          request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'})
          request.body = {to: u.expo_push_token, title: "Prana", body: "Time to affirm and visualize"}.to_json

          response = http.request(request)
          puts "The Response: #{response.body}"
        rescue => e
          puts "failed #{e}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The user successfully receives the expo_push_token, however the push notification is not received.
When I run the command `heroku run rake run_job` this is the response I get on terminal:

```
Running rake run_job on ⬢ prana-app... up, run.7732 (Free)
Running Job...
D, [2019-07-01T19:17:31.215548 #4] DEBUG -- :   User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
done!
```

What is missing in my ruby code thats preventing the push notifications from being received?

Comment: Are you sure there is at least 1 user with a token ?

Comment: @colinux my bad! The patch request from my react app wasn't working. So the expo_push_token wasn't actually being sent to the backend! Sorry and thank you!